# Inverse search with key words

Tags: 6, search

What I need is a way to search with solr in drupal for everything that DOES NOT contain the given keywords.  The default exclusion seems to require a base search first (ie at least one word to search for) however there doesn't seem to be a wildcard that will pull up just everything so I haven't been able to work out this issue.

I have tried filters but the same problem exists that I need to search for something before I can exclude anything, which in my case means I need to search for everything so that I can exclude a few things.

Any help here would be great, this is driving me crazy.